# Dúvidas em relação ao uso do stream do Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Estou praticando algumas coisas novas que veio com o Java 8 e entre essas o uso do Stream. Ouvi falar em um lugar que quando fazemos alguma ação em uma lista usando o stream, está não altera o valor da lista original, por exemplo:

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList("a", "c", "b");

lista.stream().sorted(Collector.comparing(String::toString)).forEach(System.out::println);

//saída
//a, b, c

lista.forEach(System.out::println);

//saída
//a, c, b
```

Bom, até ai tudo bem, mas digamos que eu tenha esse cenário:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Pessoa> lista = new ArrayList<Teste.Pessoa>();
        lista.add(new Pessoa("Paulo", "Gustavo"));
        lista.add(new Pessoa("Bla", "Ble"));

        Pessoa pessoa = lista.get(0);
        System.out.println(pessoa);

        mudaValor(lista);
        System.out.println(pessoa);
    }

    public static void mudaValor(List<Pessoa> lista) {
        lista.stream().forEach(pessoa -> {
            pessoa.setNome("Joquino");
        });
    }

    static class Pessoa {

        private String nome;
        private String sobreNome;

        public Pessoa(String nome, String sobreNome) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.sobreNome = sobreNome;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public String getSobreNome() {
            return sobreNome;
        }

        public void setSobreNome(String sobreNome) {
            this.sobreNome = sobreNome;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return nome;
        }
    }
}
```

Minha pergunta é: por que o meu objeto pessoa teve seu valor alterado já que ele foi alterado no `stream()` que teoricamente não altera o valor da lista real?

O objeto pessoa está com referência da memória pro mesmo objeto da lista, certo? Só que se a alteração foi feita no stream, esse não devia ter mantido o valor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paulo Gustavo, o que ocorre em seu código é que ao invocar o método `stream` em sua lista, de fato você gerou uma nova `Stream`, não uma nova instância de `ArrayList`, e mesmo que você tivesse gerado uma nova instância, veja o que ocorreria, que no caso é implementada por `ArrayList<T>`.

A classe a `ArrayList<E>` internamente guarda os valores em um *array*:

```
class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList, implements RandomAcces{
     private transient Object[] elementData;
}
```

Você pode vir a gerar outras *collections* a partir da inicial, assim, como *streams*, mas o *array* terá referências para seus objetos ainda (da *collection* inicial).

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer, as respostas estão sendo de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Você está confundindo as coisas.

`lista.stream().sorted()` retorna uma nova Stream (cópia de `lista` ordenada). Sua coleção "lista" permanece inalterada.

Porém, ambas coleções possuem referências aos mesmos objetos.

Comment: Uhum, imaginei que sim. Era duvida mesmo, como pensei que o stream nunca alterasse o valor da lista com essas ações de por exemplo, o sort, pensei que também iria servir para demais operações que envolvessem os valores da lista. Muito obrigado